# AsyncTask not called in service

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

Am presently trying to call an AsyncTask from my service, but every  time the service is called the AsyncTask that it is meant to perform is not called or not working. i have tried using this same service to call a text message method and it works but it is not working for the AsyncTask. My service class is below.

```
public class TimerLocationService extends Service {

private static boolean isRunning = false;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Timer onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    stopSelf();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Timer onBind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    stopSelf();
    isRunning = false;
   // Toast.makeText(this, "Timer onDestroy()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    isRunning = true;
    HttpGetAsyncTask g = new HttpGetAsyncTask();
    g.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.timer_message_sent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    showNotification();
    onUnbind(intent);
    onDestroy();
    quit();
   // stopService(new Intent(this,TimerLocationService.class));

}


@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "Timer onUnbind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return super.onUnbind(intent);

}
public void quit() {
    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
    System.exit(0);
}


    private class HttpGetAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


        String body ="test";
        String number ="123456789";
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            String paramMessage = body;
            String paramNumber = number;
            try {
                paramMessage = URLEncoder.encode(paramMessage, "UTF-8");
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            System.out.println("body" + paramMessage + " to :" + paramNumber);
            try {
                url = new URL("https://" + paramMessage + "&to=" + paramNumber +"&from=G.A.T.E.S&reference=your_reference");

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = isw.read();
                while (data != -1) {
                    char current = (char) data;
                    data = isw.read();
                    System.out.print(current);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }


            return paramMessage;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.get_working, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }



}


}
```

Comment: You're starting the _asynchronous_ task, and then pretty much immediately trying to kill everything in sight.

Comment: It was working fine earlier, i just removed stopself and tried again, but still not working

Comment: You shouldn't call onUnbind and onDestroy methods by yourself. These are system callbacks. Use `Context.stopService()` if you want stop service.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even notice the `stopSelf()` in `onCreate()` - which really doesn't make any sense - but I'm talking about the three calls after `showNotification();`. When you execute an `AsyncTask`, execution is not going to wait for it to finish. That's basically what the `Async` part means. Everything in `onStart()` is just going to continue. Plus, what comrade said. Plus, you should be overriding `onStartCommand()` now, instead of `onStart()`.

Comment: i used them there to try and end the service immediately it is done, is there another way to do that and how can i easily check if this particular service is running from an activity, just tried what you said and it works well

Comment: You don't need to kill the process. Simply call `stopSelf()` to end the `Service`. If you want it to happen immediately after your `AsyncTask` is done, call it from `onPostExecute()`. If you want to notify an `Activity`, you could use something like `LocalBroadcastManager`, or some other event bus implementation.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed comrade mentioned `stopService()`. Ignore that part - you just need `stopSelf()` when inside the `Service` - but everything else they said is pertinent.

Comment: thanks a lot, it works very fine right now

Comment: i have multiple services and i want to stop just one of them from an activity, how can i do that

Comment: In that case, you would use the `stopService()` method.